# rmarkdown::render leads to error when output_file path is absolute

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have the R package, one of its function - produce report.
In the inst/markdown I have a template **rep.rmd**
In the package function **ProduceReport()** I have this code:

```
  render.file <-"rep.Rmd"
  render.file <- system.file(TEMPLATES.PATH, render.file, package=getPackageName())
  render.dir <- dirname(render.file)
  pdf.file <- "example.pdf"
  rmarkdown::render(render.file , quiet = FALSE, output_format = "pdf_document", 
                 output_file = pdf.file)
```

It works.

But If I change last line to:

```
rmarkdown::render(render.file , quiet = FALSE, output_format = "pdf_document", 
                  output_file = "d:/help/me/please/example.pdf")
```

It does not work (all paths are exist). I have the error

> "! Undefined control sequence. \grffile@filename ->d:\help 
>                                \me\please\example _files/figure-... l.148 ...example_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1}"
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF  Show Traceback    Rerun with Debug 
>   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43 "

When I use this variant on linux server it also works

P.S.

I would like to emphasize, that the problem is probably not in the paths (I use standard procedure file.path() to avoid system problems, path in example only for demonstration).

Comment: In windows, the path has to be written in another way than Linux: `D:\help\me\please\example.pdf`. I think that is the error.

Comment: @J_F I don't think so, by the way I use standard function file.path(). In my description I just write this "d:/help/me/please/example.pdf" as example

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not a very good workaround, but it works on WIN

```
lol <- rmarkdown::render(render.file , quiet = TRUE,
                output_format = "pdf_document")
file.rename(lol, pdf.file)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have some problems with permissions on linux server and do not want to move file

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `output_dir` parameter of `rmarkdown::render()` function.